# How to change the language of a date picker?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

When I want to select a month, the month is in English. I would like to know how I can change the language to French please?

[image: picture of calendar]

I guess I need to configure something in the `core.module.ts`?

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReferenceDataModule,

    IdentityModule,

    NgxsModule.forRoot(
      [AppState, AuthState, ProfileState, ReferenceDataState],
      {
        developmentMode: !environment.production,
      }
    ),
    NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot({
      key: ["app", "auth", "profile", "referenceData"],
      storage: StorageOption.SessionStorage,
    }),

    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),

    TranslocoRootModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AppHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },

    {
      provide: MODAL_CONFIG_DEFAULT_OVERRIDE,
      useValue: NGX_MODAL_OPTIONS,
    },
    {
      provide: BsDatepickerConfig,
      useFactory: NGX_DATEPICKER_OPTIONS,
    },
  ],
  exports: [AppRoutingModule, TranslocoRootModule],
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

Comment: have you tried their documentation? https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/datepicker?tab=overview#locales

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
import { BsDatepickerModule, BsLocaleService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { defineLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
import { frLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/locale';

defineLocale('fr', frLocale); // <--- define

export class CoreModule {
  constructor(private localeService: BsLocaleService) {
    this.localeService.use('fr'); // <---- set to default
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this solution

```
   export class AppComponent {
    
      constructor(
        private bsLocaleService: BsLocaleService
      ) {
        this.bsLocaleService.use('ar');
      }
    
    }
```

if you are trying to use it inside **SharedModule**

```
export class SharedModule {

  constructor(
    private bsLocaleService: BsLocaleService
  ) {
    this.bsLocaleService.use('fr');
  }

}
```